# Eigenvalues bounded $\implies$ Matrix entries bounded?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $H$ is a Hermitian matrix with all its eigenvalues be bounded (below and above) say between $-n_0$ and $n_0$. Is it true that all members of the matrix $H$ is bounded (below and above) by some constant which does not depend on the order of the matrix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $-n_0 I \le H \le n_0 I$ (in the sense that $H + n_0 I$ and 
$n_0 I - H$ are positive semidefinite), $\|H\| \le n_0$ and
the matrix entries $|a_{ij}| = |e_i^T H e_j| \le \| H\| \le n_0$.

Comment: I think your norm is the supremum of the eigenvalues. Using all norms are equivalant on $\mathbb{R}^n$ we shall have a new constant $n_1$ may be different from $n_0$ in the last equation and that does not depend on the order of the matrix.

Comment: I'm using the operator norm induced by the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^n$, for which you do get $n_0$.  Other norms might not work: the constants might not be independent of dimension.

Comment: O... Its OK. This was my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Every Hermitian matrix is $H=U^\dagger DU$ where $U$ is unitary and $D$ diagonal.
In your case $D$ is contained in a compact set. As the set of unitary matrices is compact, your $H$ are contained within a compact set.

Comment: My question is that are the bounds of elements $H$ is depending on the order of the matrix $H$? As there are addition and multiplication of bounded elements, does they increase as the size of the matrix increases?

Comment: @TRUSKI If you believe an answer doesn't fully answer your original question, it is not good form to accept it because this tends to indicate to the answerer and other potential answerers that the answer you accepted is sufficient.

Comment: @eepperly you are right. Thank. I shall have that in my mind.